# React native modal date time picker is showing invalid date without debugging mode

Tags: date, react-native, datetimepicker

I am using react-native-modal-date-picker for select date and time. But when picker appearing every time it shows today date.

I have used Moment.js for formatting date.

Date picker :

```
<DateTimePicker
 isVisible={this.state.isVisible}
 onConfirm={this.handlePicker}
 onCancel={this.hidePicker}
 mode={'datetime'}
 titleIOS="Pick a Date"
 titleStyle={{fontWeight:'600',fontSize:14,color:'#606060'}}
 confirmTextStyle={{fontWeight:'600'}}
 minimumDate={today}
 date={this.state.selectedDate}
/>
```

Selected date:

```
this.setState({
  date: Moment().add(10, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A')
})

this.setState({
  selectedDate: new Date(this.state.date)
})
```

It should show my selected date instead of today date. It is working fine in debug mode but not working without debug mode.

Comment: Why are you doing `selectedDate: new Date(this.state.date)` ?

Comment: Because DateTimePicker date props need Date object data so i am converting this.state.date to Date object.

Comment: Moment returns a date object. So you don't have to do it.

Comment: Yeah but when i try to pass date={Moment().add(10, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A')} it's showing Type error props.date.getTime is not a function.

Comment: Can you help me how to pass selectedDate to date props.

Comment: Try this `date={Moment().add(10, 'days')}`

Comment: Same error occurred.

Comment: This will work `date={Moment().add(10, 'days').toDate()}`

Comment: @SanyamJain it's working. Thank you